# Having Issue On Passing Array to View From Controller in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Controller action `ActionResult` which is listing all files in directory as:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string[] txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/TextFiles/"));
    return View(txtFiles);
}
```

and in `index.cshtml` I have

```
@model List<txtFiles>   
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<ul>
@foreach (var i in Model)
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(i), "FileContent")</li>
    }
</ul>
```

but I am not sure what should I pass in `model`? I already tried
`@model List<txtFiles>` but it didn't work and I am getting this error

[image]

Comment: `@model IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: thanks haim770, and  can you please let me know what is the role of the @model IEnumerable<string> is doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You model is not a `List<txtFiles>` but a `string[]`

Change the model in your view.

`@model List<txtFiles>` should become `@model string[]` or `@model IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: Thanks Raphaël but can you please let me know what exactly the `@model IEnumerable<string>` is doing here?

Comment: In @model, you should have the TYPE of your model. `txtFiles`, which is what you send to view as model, is a `string[]` (this is what `Directory.GetFiles` returns) .  And arrays implement IEnumerable, so you can use `IEnumerable<string>` also.

Answer (score 3):

Use     @model string[] 
or 
        @model IEnumerable 
instead 
        of @model List.

Because txtFiles is not type. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `List<txtFiles>` please use `string[]` or `IEnumerable<string>` in Razor code. You tried to use `txtFiles` as a type, which is wrong becasuse it's name of variable.